# Is there a way to cancel a bucket folder delete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I kicked of a delete task of a folder in a bucket.  There is a ton of data in the folder.  It is going incredibly slow.  Is there any way to find the process and kill it?

Comment: What do you mean a delete task? Using gsutil?

Comment: Hello,  no in the Web UI under the Bucket details screen.

Comment: Are interested in canceling the deletion using only the Cloud Console?

Comment: Whatever I can do.  I thought it would be easier to find the process and kill it but if there is an easier way, I'm all for it.  Is there anyway to "reboot" a storage bucket?

Comment: "reboot" as in kill all process running on a bucket.

Comment: @user10750514 Well if you're using gsutil, by doing Ctrl^C would suffice.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it if it was started via cloud console?